# Why can't Win32::OLE talk to Excel2003 under Win2003?

Tags: perl, excel, ole

I have a Web-based Perl Win32::OLE script that uses Excel on the server side. It has been working happily for years on a Win2000 server running Excel2000. We recently upgraded to Win2003/Excel2003 and I now get the following error from the script:

```
 Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80070005: "Access is denied" at create_worksheet_lib.plx line 639
eval {...} called at create_worksheet_lib.plx line 639
```

line 639 is:

```
$Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
```

It appears that Perl no longer has access to Excel. Any Windows gurus out there that might be able to help trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the same wicked problem described in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425092/permission-denied-opening-an-excel-file-using-excel-12-0-library-vb6), however, no solution found...

Maybe troubleshooting with Procmon will reveal where the problem lies (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286198).

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the script from a command line on the server (taking the web server out of the mix)?  That's the first thing I'd try.  If it works from the command line then it's probably a permissions issue or a web server configuration issue.